# nftables и iproute2. Балансировка между двумя провайдерами

Tags: ansible, route, systemd

Пытаюсь разобраться в том, как правильно настроить маршрутизацию промаркированных nftables'ом пакетов и iproute2.
С одной стороны всё понятно. 
Добавляем таблицы в `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`

```
...
100 to_external_kis_0
101 to_external_rt_0
```

Добавляем маршруты в таблицы (external_kis_0: etth + статический ip, to_external_rt_0: pppoe + динамика)

```
ip r a default via 1.2.3.4 dev external_kis_0 proto static table to_external_kis_0
ip r a default dev external_rt_0 table to_external_rt_0
```

Добавляем правила

```
ip ru a fwmark 0x64 t external_kis_0
ip ru a fwmark 0x65 t external_rt_0
```

И маркируем пакеты nftables'ами

```
% nft add rule filter forward iif internal_0 ip saddr 10.0.0.2 tcp dport 80 meta mark set 100
% nft add rule filter forward iif internal_0 ip saddr 10.0.0.2 tcp dport 80 ct mark set mark
% nft add rule filter forward iif internal_0 ip saddr 10.0.0.3 tcp dport 80 meta mark set 101
% nft add rule filter forward iif internal_0 ip saddr 10.0.0.3 tcp dport 80 ct mark set mark
```

После этого, как я понимаю, всё должно заработать.

Но.

Я хочу это всё сделать при помощи ansible, идемпотентно.
Мне нужно всё это как минимум куда-то сохранить и как-то применить. Вдобавок необходимо, чтобы всё это применилось после перезагрузки шлюза.
С nftables всё понятно. Сгенерировать файл с правилами, написать systemd service, в котором вызывается `nft -f /path/to/file.rules` нетрудно.

Как быть с маршрутами? Как сделать правильнее? Я то конечно могу написать скрипт, выполняющий при запуске очистку и заполнение таблиц маршрутизации, но как будет более правильно?

Секция `[Route]` в systemd .network файле? Не совсем подходит для pppoe интерфейса, под него нет .network файла.
Будет ли работать, если создать external_rt_0.network, прописать в `[Match]` совпадение по имени интерфейса, опустить прочие секции и прописать маршруты в `[Route]`?

Может быть я чтото пропустил и маршруты с правилами для iproute2 можно сохранить в каком-то конфигурационном файле, откуда оно применится при загрузке?